# Why is there still some sort of race condition in this code using concurrent hashmaps?

Tags: java, concurrency, race-condition, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

I want to parse a text file and count some tokens. The file is read line by line, every line is split into tokens. The tokens are put in a list and are then processed by a method which is counting them. The tokens are stored in a concurrent hashmap with the token as the key and the amount as the value. I also need to sort this for the highest wordcount.

But it looks like I'm missing something, because I get different results on the counting.

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

private void parseFile(String file) {

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),
        StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))) {
        String line;

        ArrayList<String> tokenListForThread;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            tokenListForThread = new ArrayList<>();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, " .,:!?", false);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tokenListForThread.add(st.nextToken());
            }
            startThreads(tokenListForThread);
        }
        reader.close();
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    printWordCount();
}

private void startThreads(ArrayList<String> tokenList) {
    executorService.execute(() -> countWords(tokenList));
}

private void countWords(ArrayList<String> tokenList) {
    for (String token : tokenList) {
        int cnt = wordCount.containsKey(token) ? wordCount.get(token) : 0;
        wordCount.put(token, cnt + 1);
        /*if (wordCount.containsKey(token)){
            wordCount.put(token, wordCount.get(token)+ 1 );
        } else{
            wordCount.putIfAbsent(token, 1);
        }*/
    }
}

private void printWordCount() {
    ArrayList<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordCount.entrySet()) {
        results.add(entry.getValue());
    }

    results.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Integer tmp = results.get(i);
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}
```

Where is my mistake and if possible how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token count incrementation should be atomic, but it's not

```
int cnt = wordCount.containsKey(token) ? wordCount.get(token) : 0;
wordCount.put(token, cnt + 1);
```

Two threads with the same tokens' in token list may get the same `cnt` simultaneously, then increment it and put back. Ie total count may be lower than the real one.

To fix it without changing initial approach you may use `AtomicInteger` as `wordCount` values

```
wordCount.putIfAbsent(token, new AtomicInteger());
wordCount.get(token).incrementAndGet();
```

**Step 1** In case there is no `token` yet, but you are going to add it. Token and `zero` count should be put to the map. `putIfAbsent` method is atomic, which save you from concurrent issues.

**Step 2** Get reference to `AtomicInteger`, which corresponds to given token and increment it. This operation is thread save either.

Comment: Alternatively compute method could be used as well: wordCount.compute(token, (k, v) -> {
            if (Objects.isNull(v)) return 0;
            return v + 1;
        });